# Get Image from database by clicking on link button in gridview in asp .Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview, linkbutton

I have LinkButton in grid view

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDrvImgLic" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("intVou") %>' CommandName="viewLicImg" runat="server">Licence Image</asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

`<%#Eval("intVou") %>` is Primary key and it should show the image from database based on primary key. Does it requires any parameter for server path?
It would be fine if I can open image in new tab.

Comment: what is '<% #Eval("intVou") %>' and where it should show the image

Comment: it is primary key.
image should open in new tab

Comment: It might be `<%# Eval("intVou") %>`, there should not be space between `%` and `#`

Comment: space between % and # dont make any problem

Comment: Where and how are you showing image?

Comment: Is your Image in byte format in DB

Comment: @Bharadwaj image is in PC and DataBase...
and open in new tab

Comment: @Rajesh no, its not in byte format

Comment: if you want to show image put an image control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can instead use the Hyperlink control like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink  NavigateUrl='<%# String.Concat("~/",Eval("ImagePathField")) %>' Target="_blank" runat="server" >L</asp:HyperLink>
```

Notice that you must use "~/" to get the relative path for the image. Also you need to add `Target"_blank"` to open the image in new tab.

Hope this helps.